# OpenSSH Windows 10 Force keybased login

Tags: windows, openssh, ssh-config

So, I have configured a key based login:

1. Generated the key
2. Added it to the server side
3. Brought it to the client (and transformed to Putty format)
4. Logged in succesfully with the key

but now I would like to force all connections to use the keybased method only. Wih linux this happens by modifying sshd_config file, but I can not find it on Windows.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. A question like this would be more on topic on [su] or perhaps [sf].

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that on Windows the way is similar and the path is "C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config".

Based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration config file is found from folder path "%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config"

And for the %programdata% (is found from https://www.howtogeek.com/278562/what-is-the-programdata-folder-in-windows/) seems to be on C drive, making the full path "C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config". Though the programdata folder is hidden and it should be shown through file explorer options.